# deck.gl TripLayer plotting single path

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, deck.gl

I want to use Deck.gl to plot trips.

The data I want to use is local. I tested running local data with the example data and everything worked. However when I switched to my own coordinates I don't get anything.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Requiring in the data.

```
const DATA_URL = {
  BUILDINGS:
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/deck.gl-data/master/examples/trips/buildings.json', // eslint-disable-line
  TRIPS: require('./traindata.json'), // eslint-disable-line
};
```

Local JSON file

```
{
  "vendor": "A",
  "path": [
    [40.68138, -73.956848],
    [40.683263, -73.965838],
    [40.686113, -73.973946],
    [40.688484, -73.985001],
    [40.692338, -73.987342],
    [40.699337, -73.990531],
    [40.710197, -74.007691],
    [40.714111, -74.008585],
    [40.720824, -74.005229],
    [40.732338, -74.000495],
    [40.740893, -74.00169],
    [40.752287, -73.993391],
    [40.757308, -73.989735],
    [40.768296, -73.981736],
    [40.811109, -73.952343],
    [40.824783, -73.944216],
    [40.840719, -73.939561],
    [40.847391, -73.939704],
    [40.851695, -73.937969],
    [40.859022, -73.93418],
    [40.865491, -73.927271],
    [40.868072, -73.919899]
  ],
  "timestamps": [
    68,
    68,
    68,
    70,
    120,
    180,
    120,
    90,
    150,
    150,
    180,
    90,
    180,
    480,
    150,
    210,
    150,
    600,
    120,
    195,
    135
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are single path because you are passing only an object. The data should be an arrayf objects. Look at this data format: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/deck.gl-data/master/examples/trips/trips-v7.json